# C++ How efficiency update content of file

Tags: c++, file, filesystems, fstream, ofstream

I was wondering how can I update values in file ? Suppose I have something like this:

```
 //thread 1:    
       std::vector<int> v(10);

 //v is changed i.e. to {0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0}
       ...

 //after some time v is changed agian to: i.e. {0,0,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,0}

 //etc

 //thread 2: (is a react thread)   
 //apart from synchronization

       std::fstream file;
       file.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::out);
       while(true)
       {
           //file.seekp(0, std::ios_base::beg); -> with this almost works, but update takes too long
           for (auto const& e : v)
               file << e << ',';
           file.flush();
       }
```

Due to the performance efficiency open and close file in every iteration is non-starter, so I want to open the file once and then only updates values in file, but after first iteration file is not updated.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better in terms of efficiency to update the values internally in a variable or vector (whether by update you mean replace or add) and write the result only once at the end of the process. It would be faster and would avoid to keep the file opened during the whole process.

Comment: this question doesn't have enough details to help. Also I suspect [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) since code comments contains some information about threads so most probably problem is proper synchronization.

Comment: Mos of the time, efficiency is tightly coupled with use scenario. It's difficult to answer your question without knowing what kind of changes can be made to the vector.

Comment: @Fareanor I wanted to do that but what in case when some an unexpected error occurs ? I can lost all information and I can finish with nothing saved in file.

Comment: *Due to the performance efficiency open and close file in every iteration is non-starter*  Really?  How do you know that?  You've benchmarked it?  And you have documented performance requirements that your benchmarks demonstrate that you can't meet?  Unless you know you have a performance problem that's been revealed by actual testing, you can't know that.  In this case, all the data needed to open the file over and over is likely cached by the kernel, and it may well be more than fast enough.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I performed an easy measurement (based on time). I checked how long each iterations takes: with open/close in each iteration it takes: ~ 140000 - 700000 ns, when it is opened only once it takes: max: 6000 - 12000 ns on my hardware, so this is a noticeable difference, I prepared sth similar but on one thread: https://wandbox.org/permlink/xQJHCurW2Zqtri61

Comment: @bladzio You can still save the data even if an error occur by catching all the exceptions/errors that could be raised/encountered. Of course, I agree that you can do nothing if someone kills your program abruptly.

Comment: @Fareanor you're right but how about a power outage ? :)

Comment: @bladzio Yes, you are right, but I really don't know if the file will still be saved in case of power outage while you are keeping it opened. Maybe it could be worth to check, if anyone knows.

Comment: @Fareanor that's true, but if I flush in every iteration the state then I can at most lose state from one iteration :)

Comment: @bladzio Ah ok. Whatever, it is up to you to chose what is better for your use case. It was just a proposal to gain efficiency, I could be wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using [std::call_once](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) and [std::once_flag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag)

```
#include <mutex>
std::once_flag flag;

//in thread 2
std::call_once(flag, file.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::out));
```

`file.open()` will be called only once.

Comment: obviously he wants to update file frequently (multiple times), so what kind of magic can improve performance with sue of  `std::call_once`?